# mysql comparing force BINARY

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. In one I have column like INT and in other I have row like VARCHAR where I wait user id or unique id for quest with letters...I want compare if INT = VARCHAR in mysql query. I am using:

BINARY int_row = BINARY varchar_row

is this ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're comparing only numbers, it won't matter. There will be an [implicit conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html) anyway so that the `varchar` and `int` fields can be compared.

The only problem I can think of is if the varchar field can contain values like this:

```
1ABCDEFGHIJK
```

you may get into trouble here, because  a conversion of this varchar into a number would result in `1`!

To make sure, I would tend to use

```
BINARY CAST(int_row AS CHAR) = BINARY varchar_row
```

but this can be overly paranoid - correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yea you are right.... this is exactly my problem. If string starting with number it is automaticaly conveted to starting number therefore I use BINARY for comparasion and it works for me fine.. but I wan to know if code is allright or it is just lucky....